# Objectify queries: filter by date

Tags: java, google-app-engine, date, gwt, objectify

I am using GAE and I need to write an Objectify query that asks for the elements created after September 1st.

The dateCreated field is Java.util.Date and it is stored in this format 2012-11-29 16:03:59.494000.

This request is NOT working:

```
   public List<MyElement> listAllFromUser(String userId)
    {
        Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
        Query<MyElement> q=ofy.query(MyElement.class).filter("dateCreated >", "2013-09-01 00:00:00");

        List<MyElement> results = q.list();

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Either you are storing as a date or as string. No such thing as storing as date with format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your column needs to be indexed

   @Indexed
   protected Date dateCreated;
2. You can sort only by one column in a request (> and < and != are all considered sorting since the index is sorted, then analyzed)
3. You can group dates by loosing precision:  2012-11-29 16:03:59.494000 becomes  2012-11-29
   this way, you can use == safely. Create a column for each precision you want (day, week, month). In general, try relying the least possible on sorting operations: sooner or later you will be happy for that choice