# NoSQL select timeRanges that cover a given timeRange

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I am using Google App Engine's Datastore as my database. I have a bunch of users let's call them providers that have given what time ranges they are available for the week. Like 3-4 p.m. and 4:30-7:30 p.m. Then, another user comes along and says I want to see who is available from 5-6 p.m. on this day. How do I get the list of users that have said they are available from 5-6 p.m. What is the best way to model the data and get this result?

Comment: There is no real way to select for a given range.  if you are working with 30min slots, then consider a bitmap or repeating property that stores all the 30min slots of availability and turn a range query into an or query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Hoffman's comment is the correct answer. Use time increments and store variables for each increment. Turin is correct if there is only one time range that you are available, but with multiple time ranges the problem becomes very different.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know what language do you use. 
I assume that you use Java and Objectify. Code below omits some details. Essentially you need to **index** **fromDate and toDate** and after to filter providers based on parameters got from user input.

```
public class Provider {

    ...
    @index Date availableFrom;
    @index Date availableTo; 
    ...

}

public class ProviderService {

    @ApiMethod(name = "getByRange")
    public List<Provider> getByRange( @Named("availableFrom") String   
                    availableFrom, @Named("availableTo") String availableTo{

        List<Provider> providers=   
            ofy().load().type(Provider.class).filter("availableFrom >=",  
              availableFrom).filter("availableTo <=", availableTo).list();
        return providers;
}
```

[Objectify queries](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries)

[Filter by date example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589461/objectify-queries-filter-by-date)

[Multiple filters example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547895/objectify-multiple-filters-doesn%C2%B4t-work-with-cron-job)